# Include Path location for xerces C++

Tags: c++, header, xerces

I'm trying to build xerces in Ubuntu. I am getting a file not found error with one of the headers. This is a basic question but how does the compiler know the location of xercesc? I have defined XERCESROOT, does it use that?

```
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMLSInput.hpp>
```

https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html

Answer (score 2):

The compiler knows the location of the header files based on the build configuration. In gcc it is possible to define the header directory through -I flag (e.g. -I/usr/local/include).

In order to check which directory the compiler is looking for your header file see the string showing the last compiler command before the error.

You have to find something like gcc -I etc... where directory is the directory where it is searching.

Anyway, I've just compiled xerces-c-3-1-3 from command line on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without defining XERCES_ROOT using the following steps:

1. Download from [this site](http://it.apache.contactlab.it//xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.1.3.tar.gz)
2. tar zxvf xerces
3. ./configure
4. make

and it works without error.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I also was able to compile 3.1.3, but unfortunately I have to use 2.7.0 which I cannot get to compile. I'll look into specifying an include path.

Comment: Do you need 2.7.0 for a specific reason? I've not found source for this version on the official site (http://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/2/) but only 2.8.0. Could 2.8.0 be compatible with your source code? It's available also as precompiled binaries (http://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/2/binaries/).